# Python If-clause is not accepted (syntax)

Tags: python, syntax

I have got a quite simple if clause. I tried everything, but it still Outputs a Syntax error.

```
if(NOT((element.find('@') > 0) OR (element.isDigit) OR (element.find("REMINDER") > 0))):
      doStuff()
```

Now as you can see, it's a negotiated clause with 3 Arguments, connected with OR. I checked the Arguments and they seemed to work. Any ideas?

Comment: NOT and OR are not valid python syntax

Comment: @roganjosh `NOT` as used here is valid syntax, but not a valid name.

Comment: @klausd. I'm confused. Am I missing something or is this semantics (which I'm definitely not great with)?

Comment: @roganjosh: Syntax errors manifest at compile time. The fact that `NOT()` is not a defined function (as it is currently used) makes it a `NameError`. If OP had not used parentheses, then it would be a `SyntaxError` indeed.

Comment: Im suspecting semantics and perhaps you're right, but `) OR (` could not be a valid anything, even if the name existed

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes it could. Define a function `def OR(*args): pass` and it's valid.

Comment: Used like above `NOT` could be a callable (like a function). The syntax is valid, but `NOT` has to be defined.

Comment: @timpietzcker and what of the leading `)` in what I posted? There's no operator before `OR` and, while I can't test right now, I'm not sure that it is valid. I didn't  intend for this debate but fair enough :) I'll accept that I may have used the wrong words here

Answer (score 3):

Python is case sensitive (and doesn't need that many parentheses). Try:

```
if not (element.find('@') > 0 or element.isDigit or element.find("REMINDER") > 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

The python boolean operators are case sensitive, as you can see in this section of 
[the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

In this case, you need to replace `NOT` and `OR` with their lowercase forms (`not` and `or`) for your condition to work as you intend.

Also, you can remove some of the parenthesis and the condition will still work. The parenthesis you have are correct, but you can also write it like this and get the same result (with less characters, which is more readable in my opinion for this case):

```
if not (element.find('@') > 0 or element.isDigit or element.find("REMINDER") > 0):
    doStuff()
```